# Sort multidimensional array by inner value,needs key preserved

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

My array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 10.00
            [price] => 19.00

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [package] =>  kgs
            [qty] => 1.00
            [price] => 2.00

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 25.00
            [price] => 50.00

        )

)
```

I need to sort this array based on price ascending value.i used **usort** for this.My code is looks like

```
usort($array, function ($b, $a) { return $b['price'] - $a['price']; });
```

then I got the resulting array as

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package] =>  kgs
            [qty] => 1.00
            [price] => 2.00

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 10.00
            [price] => 19.00

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 25.00
            [price] => 50.00

        )

)
```

But my actual needs is that getting result with preserving keys.that is,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [package] =>  kgs
            [qty] => 1.00
            [price] => 2.00

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 10.00
            [price] => 19.00

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [package] => Bag
            [qty] => 25.00
            [price] => 50.00

        )

)
```

What will I do ??? Please help me.

Comment: Use `uasort` and check

Comment: Instead of `usort` use `uasort`

Comment: but while I trying to sort with price 50.55 and 50.00. usort($array, function ($b, $a) { return $b['price'] - $a['price']; }); code didn't work as I expected :(

Comment: usort($array, function ($b, $a) { return $b['price'] > $a['price']; }) 
Solved my confusion while trying with 50.55 and 50.00 as inputs. :-)